# An incompatible mapping has been encountered between [class Entity.Classification] and [class Entity.Cls_area_map]

Tags: jpa, mapping, cardinality

I'm new to JPA and I am having some difficulty creating some entities.

In the application I am building it is possible to classify some entities according to some area and subarea defined in a database.

The relevant tables are these four ones:

1) classification

```
+-------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type                  | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ID          | int(11) unsigned      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| pID         | int(11) unsigned      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| reference   | varchar(300)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| link        | varchar(255)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

2) cls_area_map

```
+---------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| class   | int(11) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| idarea  | int(11) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| subarea | int(11) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| id      | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
+---------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

3) area

```
+--------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field  | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| idarea | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| label  | varchar(255)     | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
+--------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

4) subarea

```
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| area_idarea | int(11) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| label       | varchar(255)     | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| ID          | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

In `classification` I store general classification information, and in `cls_area_map` I try to connect the general information to the areas of classification (defined in `area` and `subarea`).

When I try to add the classification-area mapping information to my `Classification` and my `Cls_area_map` entity classes I run into trouble.

I get the error:

```
An incompatible mapping has been encountered between [class Entity.Classification] and [class Entity.Cls_area_map]. This usually occurs when the cardinality of a mapping does not correspond with the cardinality of its backpointer..
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong about the cardinality. This is what I added to `Classification` to create the relationship:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "id")
private List<Cls_area_map> cls_area;
```

and in `Cls_area_map`:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "class",referencedColumnName = "ID")
@ManyToOne(optional=false)
private Classification classy;
```

Any explanations/hints?

(and what is meant by `backpointer`?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mappedBy` indicates that the entity in this side is the inverse of the relationship. So entity name should be used instead of foreign key.

The doc says

> mappedBy refers to the property name of the association on the owner
>   side.

It is classy in your case, so use

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "classy")
private List<Cls_area_map> cls_area;
```

**See also:**

[**mappedBy**](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html#mappedBy%28%29)